# SQL: How can I find the total and average value in one SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate, average

I would like to calculate the total amount of expenditure and the calculate the average value from the number of rows like this:

```
SELECT AVG(SUM(expenditure)) from INCOME;
```

However, there is a error say "misuse of aggregate function sum()"

how can I achieve this?

Comment: What would the average of the sum be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't calculate the average of the total sum as there is only one total.

The average `AVG()` function already calculates the total as part of its logic.

This is what you want:

```
SELECT AVG(expenditure) as AverageExpenditure, 
       SUM(expenditure) as TotalExpenditure
from INCOME;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT AVG(expenditure) AS avg_exp, SUM(expenditure) AS sum_exp FROM INCOME;
```